# What is the value set for X-Forwarded-For header by Google App Engine URL Fetch?

Tags: google-app-engine, urlfetch, request-headers

Documentation says (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/overview.html#Request_Headers):

> These headers are set to accurate values by App Engine, as appropriate

Does the value for X-Forwarded-For included some identity of the gae application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, X-Forwarded-For appears to be unset in requests made by URLFetch.

You can verify this for yourself by going to http://shell.appspot.com/ and doing a URLFetch for a site that echoes HTTP requests - for example, http://www.showhttprequest.com/ . App Engine sets the User Agent string to "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)", but doesn't set X-Forwarded-For at all.

Comment: This answer is marked correct but the latest status can be seen in ade's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882443/what-is-the-value-set-for-x-forwarded-for-header-by-google-app-engine-url-fetch/2956172#2956172)

Comment: The site `www.showhttprequest.com` appears to no longer exist, but this still appears to be app engine's behavior as of 2/2014.

Answer (score 3):

If you go to shell.appspot.com and run the following code:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
url = 'http://www.showhttprequest.com/'
result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
print result.content
```

You will see that (as of sometime near the end of 2009) AppEngine now puts the appid into the user-agent header. So your user-agent ends up looking like:

```
AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine; appid: shell)
```